# OData HttpPost -> Request data passing as null as always for model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am using ODataController in our application, when we are passing model object as request data to http post method, it is passing as null value.

Below values are added in header:

```
content-type: application/json
accept-type : application/json
```

screenshot below

[image]

we are using the postman rest client plugin to check the request and response flow.

Controller Code:

```
    [ControllerName("Bills")]
    public class BillsController : ODataController
    {

    [HttpPost]
        [ODataRoute]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(Bills bills)
        {
            List<Bills> projectList = new List<Bills>();

            projectList = billingPostgresBusinessService.GetAllBills();

            return Ok(projectList);
        }
}
```

PostMan data:

```
Url : https://localhost:44367/odata/v1/Bills
```

Model Class

```
public class Bills
    {
        public Bills()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public List<ProjectDetail> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectDetail
    {
        public string AmountDueDate { get; set; }
        public string TotalDueDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Request Data:

```
{
            "projectId": 1000,
            "projectName": "Project0",
            "details": [
                {
                    "amountDueDate": "1/21/2015",
                    "totalDueDate": "1/25/2015"
                },
                {
                    "amountDueDate": "12/11/2011",
                    "totalDueDate": "12/15/2011"
                }
            ]
}
```

**Update:**

When i change header like below, it is working fine

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

how we can pass application/json as content-type to make the post action should work properly

Comment: Do you register the `Bill` object as an entity with the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`? (Something like: `builder.EntitySet<Bill>("Bills")`)

Comment: @GwigWam yes we have added this configuration. please see updated question on top